# how to disable swagger for production in nestjs

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I am adding the swagger-ui to my nestjs app. I need to disable that swagger in production. I searched over the nestjs documentation, I didn't find any useful. I need a good resource or guidance to disable the swagger in production.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the ways to solve this is as below. Wrap the Swagger Documentation-related code within if block "**process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'**".

URL: https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-the-difference-between-development-and-production

**.evn file**

```
MONGO_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/quotesdb"
NODE_ENV=production
```

**main.ts file**

```
import 'dotenv/config';

import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors();

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const options = new DocumentBuilder()
      .setTitle('Quotes Api')
      .setDescription('Quotes API Description')
      .setVersion('1.1')
      .addTag('quotes')
      .build();

    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
    SwaggerModule.setup('api/swagger', app, document);
  }

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

[image]

Comment: if `@nestjs/swagger` is only a dev dependency, then `main.ts` file will throw an error while running it after the build that it can't find `@nest/swagger`. which might break the current solution

Comment: if you are talking in terms of docker since the same image needs to be deployed in lower(dev, qa,int, for instance) and prod, then putting the swagger in dev deps anyways is not the correct flow. because images are built pre deployment and we cant do, if else in that.